# How to remove <a> tag only when xml node is empty

Tags: jquery, xml

First of all, I apologize for my poor English.

I'm using jquery plugin jParse which parse xml easily. here is the demo page(http://jparse.kylerush.net/demo)

I've tried a couple times but can't seem to figure out how to remove `<a>` tag if the href is empty.

Here is my code:

```
elementTag: ['category', 'pubDate', 'title', 'link', 'description'];
output: '<dl><dt class="jpet00">jpet01</dt><dd><strong><a href="jpet03">jpet02</a></strong><br />jpet04</dd></dl>';
```

if the xml 'link' node is empty, i want to output like this

```
output: '<dl><dt class="jpet00">jpet01</dt><dd><strong>jpet03jpet02</strong><br />jpet04</dd></dl>';
```

I tried  *$("a[href='']").remove()*  but it didn't work.

Are there any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you calling `$("a[href='']").remove()` - it should be in your `finish()` function shown in the demo. If this is where you are using it it may be that the href is not entirely empty. Try:

```
function finish() {
    jQuery('#jparse-meta').remove();
    $('a').each(function() {
        var string = $(this).text().replace(/\s{2,}/g, '')
        if (string == "") {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT 1** as requested in comments

```
function finish() {
    jQuery('#jparse-meta').remove();
    $('a[href=""]').each(function() {
        $(this).parent('strong').html($(this).text());
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, Inrbob. Thanks for your help.
I tried your code but it didn't work.
But thanks to your advice, now I understand I was calling `$("a[href='']").remove()` in wrong place. so i put it in finish() function, then it worked!
but another problem...it removes also the text inside the <a> tag.
Could you solve this?

Comment: So you want to remove the anchor but not the text? Since its in strong tags you could try adding this to the each code above: $('a[href=""]').parent('strong').html($(this).text());

Comment: i'm sorry i can't understand where i have to put it. could you show the whole code?

Comment: YaY!! it work out! THANK YOU Inrbob. Thanks for your great help.
I am so happy :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test, but something like it might do the job:

```
 $("a").each( function() {
       if($(this)).text= "") {
          $(this).remove();
       }
    }
  )
```

Comment: Hi, Saul. Thanks for your help. I tried your advice but it didn't work. then I chaged the code like this `$(function(){ $('a[href*=""]').each(function(){ $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); }); });` it seems work. but only for normal source but jparse output source...i don't know why.